# Change column values in pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

df:

```
      A
0    219
1    590
2    272
3    945
4    175
5    930
6    662
7    472
8    251
9    130
```

I am trying to create a new column quantile based on which quantile the value falls in, for example:

```
if value > 1st quantile : value = 1
if value > 2nd quantile : value = 2
if value > 3rd quantile : value = 3
if value > 4th quantile : value = 4
```

Code:

```
f_q = df['A'] .quantile (0.25)
s_q = df['A'] .quantile (0.5)
t_q = df['A'] .quantile (0.75)
fo_q = df['A'] .quantile (1)


index = 0
for i  in range(len(test_df)):

   value = df.at[index,"A"]
   if value > 0 and value <= f_q:
       df.at[index,"A"] = 1

   elif value > f_q and value <= s_q:
       df.at[index,"A"] = 2

   elif value > s_q and value <= t_q:
       df.at[index,"A"] = 3

   elif value > t_q and value <= fo_q:
       df.at[index,"A"] = 4


   index += 1
```

The code works fine. But I would like to know if there is a more efficient pandas way of doing this. Any suggestions are helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using [`pd.qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/generated/pandas.qcut.html):

```
>>> pd.qcut(df.A, 4).cat.codes + 1
0    1
1    3
2    2
3    4
4    1
5    4
6    4
7    3
8    2
9    1
dtype: int8
```

(Gives me exactly the same result your code does.)

You could also call [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) on the `qcut` result:

```
>>> np.unique(pd.qcut(df.A, 4), return_inverse=True)[1] + 1
array([1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1])
```

Or, using [`pd.factorize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.factorize.html) (note the slight difference in the output):

```
>>> pd.factorize(pd.qcut(df.A, 4))[0] + 1
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3, 1])
```

Comment: @vikky Added more options, if needed.

Comment: cool Thanks. i will compare the performances of the options and will post that for future readers.